# Python Import error , auto install

Tags: python, linux, python-import

I wonder, if the required python library to be imported is not yet installed , and you need to import it , is there any way that can auto-install it if the library doesn't exists.

My python scripts often include custom libraries that are not installed by default , and those scripts land on different machines with python installed but not the custom libraries , so i want a way such that the required library gets installed automatically if import doesn't succeed.

More specifically , there is a Jenkins job that can run the script on any of the 500 slaves , and i don't have to install custom libs on each of them , instead on the slave where the job lands automatically , the custom lib should be installed if there is some import error.

Comment: You can use virtualenv together with pip as one solution. The problem with automatic install without these is the sudo/admin right with security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common practice is to list libraries you use in [requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) file. Then users of your script will be able to install all the dependencies via one command.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use pyinstaller and provide a ready to use package (e.g. exe file on Windows) to your customers. So even if the other computer has no internet access to download missing packages, your script will work.